# Apache2 - Sub domains, I just cant get them to work

Tags: networking, server, apache2

Pinging my subdomain works, it shows my IP. But, when I go to the subdomain, I get the website cannot be found.

My config file (rp.penguins.pw.config in sites-available.)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName rp.penguins.pw
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rp.penguins.pw
</VirtualHost>
```

The directory /var/www/rp.penguins.pw exists. If you need any more information, just comment and I'll give it to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Take a look at error and access log. Apache should log your successful and unsuccessful attempts. It should give you a clue what is wrong.

Comment: How do I look at the log? @nobody

Comment: You probably have two main log files `/var/log/apache2/access.log` and `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. You can open them in any editor or text file viewer. An example of such programs is gedit. Start gedit and open log files. You can also do it in terminal window. In that case I recommend less: `less /var/log/apache2/access.log` and `less /var/log/apache2/error.log`